# Rails observer not being triggered on seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, observer-pattern

I am having an issue getting observers to trigger when using seed data in my development database.

app/models/item_observer.rb:

```
require 'grit'

class ItemObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def create(item)
    Grit::Repo.init_bare(item.repository_path)
    logger.debug "doneit"
  end
end
```

db/seeds.rb:

```
admin_rank = UserRank.create!({
  :title => 'Administrator',
  :permissions => Marshal.dump(Hash.new)
})

admin = User.create!({
  :username => 'admin',
  :password => 'password',
  :user_rank => admin_rank
})

url_operators = Item.create!({
  :creator => admin,
  :title => 'test game/something #1?',
  :description => 'this is an example of a game entry!?\'"#<>... obviously.'
})
```

And in my config/application.rb i have the line:

config.active_record.observers = :item_observer

Why would the observer's create method not be triggering on rake db:seed RAILS_ENV=development? I can create the Grit repository by calling Grit::Repo.init_bare from the ItemController.

(BTW, my rails version is 3.0.3).

Comment: Just to isolate this further, can you try removing the `!` from you create methods; perhaps `create!` doesn't fire the `create` observer.

Comment: Is the item created? Try creating an item and have a peep at the logs. Maybe that can give you something if in case there's an error.

Comment: removing the bang from create made no difference, and the item was created. Turns out the "create" observer method doesn't actually work in this instance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should it not be after_create instead of just create in the observer

```
require 'grit'

class ItemObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer

  def after_create(item)
    Grit::Repo.init_bare(item.repository_path)
    logger.debug "doneit"
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm you're right, I must've forgotten to try that after moving my data from fixtures to seed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Another reason that I found when trying to debug observers in development was that I needed to enable class cache.

```
 config.cache_classes = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you have the configuration `config.active_record.observers = :item_observer` set in config/development.rb file